# solution recommendation to store AES encryption key of Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: encryption, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Hi Hyperledger Experts:

In some cases, some organizations in a channel have the requirement to encrypt their data on the fabric network. Please refer to https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html#chaincode-encryption . And the AES encryption key and decryption key are needed.

So there is a need to store some organizations' encryption key and decryption key. The fabric documentation also mentioned "If you encrypt the data then you will need to provide a means to share the decryption keys". Please refer to https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Fabric-FAQ.html

So the question is: what is the advisable way to store the AES encryption/decryption keys? Where to store them?

Apart from fabric network, do we need a separate centralized database to store them? Or can we directly store them on fabric network, and only let specified organizations to get them? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in data security but I believe your problem can be solved using Private Data present in hyperledger fabric framework itself.

It is confidential data that is stored in a private database on each authorized peer, logically separate from the channel ledger data. Access to this data is restricted to one or more organizations on a channel via a private data collection definition. Unauthorized organizations will have a hash of the private data on the channel ledger as evidence of the transaction data.

Refer to [docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private_data_tutorial.html) to understand how to use this to store your AES keys.

Comment: Thanks. So you mean using Private Data Collection to store the AES keys for some specified organizations? I think it is a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, It looks like it serves your purpose while ensuring unauthorized organizations don't have access to it.